# Eager loading failing for Child Collection in EF 4.3.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, eager-loading

I have the following classes:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Expression Criteria {get;set;}
}

public class Expression
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Parameter> Parameters {get;set;}
}

public class Parameter
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public MyType Type {get;set;}
}

public class MyType
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to eagerly load the entire configuration object using:

```
dbContext.Configurations.Select(i => i.Criteria).Include(i => i.Parameters.Select(j => j.Type)).ToList()
```

I am however getting null for the Parameters property and it is not getting fetched.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dbContext.Configurations.Select(i => i.Criteria).Include("Parameters").Include("Parameters.Type").ToList()
```